# How to implement pull to refresh on existing hybrid app built using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have currently developed a hybrid app using cordova for ios & android. I wanted to add a feature which is pull to refresh in the app. I couldnt find any satisfying solutions to it. I have found many solutions for native app but none for hybrid app. Help me out here if possible thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cordova App using javascript, I think PulltoRefresh.js is the best choose, very easy to add to your code.

```
PullToRefresh.init({
 mainElement: '#main', // above which element?
 onRefresh: function (done) {
 setTimeout(function () {
  done(); // end pull to refresh
  alert('refresh');
}, 1500);
```

}
});

See demo at [author site](https://www.boxfactura.com/pulltorefresh.js/)

Comment: Do I need to install pulltofresh or just create a js file add the script in it & initialize on my HTML file? Could you tell me steps to do it please? Thanks

Comment: @Melvita could you tell me how to do it?